# ZeroDivisionError when using sklearn's BaggingClassifier with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to improve a perfectly working Bernoulli Naive Bayes model with bagging.

But when I try to cross-validate the `BaggingClassifier`, I get a very unexpected `ZeroDivisionError` coming from parallel.py.

I've tried to change all the parameters I know, rebooted python but nothing worked.

Here is a reproducible example with a binary-modified `iris` dataset:

```
#%% run
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris


data = load_iris()
data.targetbin = (data.target!=0).astype("int")




param_grid2={'max_samples' : np.linspace(0.5,1.0,3),
            'base_estimator__alpha':np.linspace(0.1,1,3),
            'base_estimator__binarize':[*np.linspace(0.0,1,3)],
            'base_estimator__fit_prior':[True,False]}


param_grid2={'max_samples' :[0.7]}


clf = GridSearchCV(
        BaggingClassifier(
                BernoulliNB(),
                n_estimators = 10, max_features = 0.5),
        param_grid2,
        scoring = "accuracy",
        verbose=-1)


clf.fit(data.data, data.targetbin)
```

And here is the stacktrace of my error:

> [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1
>   concurrent workers. Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 33, in 
>       clf.fit(data.data, data.targetbin)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py",
>   line 722, in fit
>       self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py",
>   line 1191, in _run_search
>       evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py",
>   line 711, in evaluate_candidates
>       cv.split(X, y, groups)))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py",
>   line 917, in **call**
>       if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py",
>   line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
>       self._dispatch(tasks)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py",
>   line 716, in _dispatch
>       job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib_parallel_backends.py",
>   line 184, in apply_async
>       callback(result)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py",
>   line 306, in **call**
>       self.parallel.print_progress()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py",
>   line 806, in print_progress
>       if (is_last_item or cursor % frequency):
>
> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's a bug. It's raised on the print_progress line. In this case it's better to open an issue on GitHub sklearn repo.

Comment: ok, I'll do this, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to debug the lib and found `self.verbose` for `sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py` is `-1`, however it's supposed to be at least `0` by default. So I think it's a bug.

Comment: You are right, setting  verbose to 0 or 1 solved the problem, thanks. I've posted the bug on [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13784#issuecomment-489320881) and they said they do some check that verbose is not negative first and make the doc a little clearer (for now it just says that the higher the more info).